# Should I use the Borderlands 2 Premier Club codes before Gaige's release? 

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my preorder bonuses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84665/how-do-i-get-my-preorder-bonuses)

I recently pre-ordered Borderlands 2 for the PS3 but don't fully understand the code system. So when I punch in my premier club code before Gaige's official release will I still be able to download her for free?

Comment: depends on your code. what does it start with?

Comment: I won't have the game till it's release on Friday so I dunno what it starts with

Comment: The referenced answer is for Steam on PC, but it still applies to you.