# Borderlands 2 Pre-Order Codes

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my preorder bonuses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84665/how-do-i-get-my-preorder-bonuses)

I pre-orderes borderlands 2 for the xbox from gamestop but didn't get any codes for the pre-ordered items! where should they have been and what should i do?

Comment: go to the store?

Answer (score 0):

If ordered online, they should have been e-mailed to you.

- Check your junk mail folder.
- If not in there, contact Gamestop support.

If in a retail store, go back to the retail store and ask them what's up?