# Must I have an active XBox Live Gold account to get the pre-order bonus for Borderlands 2?

Tags: borderlands-2, xbox-network

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get my preorder bonuses?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84665/how-do-i-get-my-preorder-bonuses)

Do you need to have an active XBox Live Gold account to get the pre-order bonus for Borderlands 2?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, Gold isn't necessary. You can redeem the codes for the pre-order bonuses just like you would redeem a points card.