# How can I install DLCs?

Tags: borderlands-2

I bought Borderlands 2 some time ago. I was playing recently when I saw a new menu entry labeled "Downloadable Content". On clicking it, I saw 3 DLCs that were purchased, but not downloaded. I pressed enter to download, but was redirected to an instance of the Steam browser on the home page. No reference whatsoever to the DLCs.

How can I download them?

**Update**

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: A screenshot of what it looked like would help

Comment: A screenshot of what?

Comment: The thing you are seeing - in menu what it looks like

Comment: Added the screenshot as you asked.

Comment: That doesn't actually look like any DLC that's ever been sold.  In fact, the titles read like placeholders.

Comment: @Radhil Borderlands 2 did have some pre-order bonuses.  They were: 1 Golden Key, the Vault Hunter's Relic, and the Gearbox Gunpack... in addition to the Mechromancer class (but that appears separately).

Comment: On a side note, [this page](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Golden_Key) has a number of SHIFT keys you can use to unlock certain themed skins, themed weapons, and (not kidding here) hundreds of Golden Keys.

Answer (score 3):

**tl;dr - It's a bug.**

According to [multiple](https://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/612823460276837717/) [Steam](http://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/3/358415738210095438/) [threads](http://steamcommunity.com/app/49520/discussions/0/358415206092498334/), several people have the same problem with these entries showing up in their Borderlands 2 in-game DLC list.

The general consensus response seems to be that the in-game list has been made inaccurate since they repackaged several items, and that the only accurate DLC list is from the Steam store.  If you do not have a DLC tab in Steam for this game, then you have no DLC available to download.

Answer (score 2):

If Steam isn't auto-installing the DLC, you can tell Steam to install it by doing the following:

1. Open your Steam library.
2. Right-click the entry for Borderlands 2 and choose Properties.
   [image: Steam Properties]
3. Navigate to the DLC tab.
   [image: Borderlands 2 Properties]
4. Make sure the boxes next to the DLCs you want installed are checked.  I recommend checking all the boxes.  Note: You may have to scroll down depending on how many DLCs you own.
   [image: Borderlands 2 DLC list]
5. Click Close.

Borderlands 2 should begin updating if you checked or unchecked any of the boxes.

If all the DLCs are already checked, then you may want to "Verify integrity of game files" from the Local Files tab.

Comment: I do not have the DLC tab.

Comment: @ruipacheco Hmm, that's odd.  However, apparently there's another question that talks about the [Pre-Order DLC specifically](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84665/how-do-i-get-my-preorder-bonuses).  Not sure if anything in that question is useful.

Comment: @ruipacheco If that doesn't work, the next thing I'd recommend is to create a SHIFT account if you haven't done so already.  This is done from the... Extras menu I believe (I don't currently have BL2 installed).

Comment: What's a SHIFT account?

Comment: @ruipacheco It's used to activate various codes given out by Gearbox. I'm just wondering if one is needed to properly activate the Pre-order DLCs as well.  As for other SHIFT codes, the site Orcz has a [list of all the codes](http://orcz.com/Borderlands_2:_Golden_Key), although the ones listed in red no longer work.